# Tried To register two Views with the same name RTCVideoView in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I am trying to run my app on Android but I am getting this error I don't know why I am getting this, I don't know what is causing this error in my project
I have tried tried many ways to resolve this issue but Still wasn't able to resolve this issue.

**Tried To register two Views with the same name RTCVideoView**

My Package.json is

```
{
  "name": "Hello World",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "connectycube-reactnative": "^1.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-cache-store": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.212.0",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^1.6.7",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-view-overflow": "^0.0.4",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.75.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-prompt": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any Help Would be Appreciated.

Comment: do you have a yarn.lock or package-lock.json? Perhaps your app is trying to load two different versions of `react-native-webrtc` where `RTCVideoView` is defined.

Comment: I do have react-native-webrtc in my pakage-lock.json

Comment: What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: If there is just one that's fine, I'm just wondering if one of your other dependencies depends on a different version of `react-native-webrtc` that doesn't match the one in your `package.json`. For example see this thread for a similar issue with conflicting versions of `react-native-svg`: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/591

Comment: According to error you are using **VideoView** in you code. It happens when you install or register same view multiple times.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this exact same issue. I am using connectycube and react-native-webrtc. I have checked and all versions of react-native-webrtc are 1.75.1. Did you find a solution to the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is just clean up the cache by the following command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

This will resolve your problem most probably

Answer (score 2):

The version of `react-native-webrtc` you have specified in your `package.json` is different from the version that `connectycube-reactnative` depends on. The latest `connectycube-reactnative` (1.8.0) depends on `"react-native-webrtc": "1.69.1"`.

Double check the dependency of the version you have installed by looking at the `node_modules/connectycube-reactnative/package.json` and match the version specified in your package.json to the version the `connectycube-reactnative` requires.

Comment: Changes the version to 1.69.1 but its still showing same error

Comment: I guess this is something related more to Xcode project configuration , probably a WebRTC lib is not linked properly

Answer (score 0):

The @arzundo answer is correct

And seems this issue is addressed in latest releases here https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-reactnative-samples/tree/master/RNVideoChat so you can simply try to pull the latest master